# Usps shipping labels dimensions

Tags: usps

As from what the subject says do anyone know the dimensions of a shipping label for domestic and international shipping?. I have read that labels are printed as 4x6" in 8.5x11" self adhesive paper. Is 4x6" the standard of the shipping labels?

Thank you and more power.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no standard label size, that you are forced to use.  I have used several combinations of sizes.  I primarily use Avery labels and print onto them.  You can open up MS Word, go to Envelopes/Labels or similar option and it will given you a list of sizes of the various labels.